# Is the set of all real numbers defined under the Axiom of Infinity in ZFC?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that the set of all natural numbers is defined as an infinite set under the Axiom of Infinity, but I'm having a hard time using $\exists S [\emptyset \in S \land (\forall x\in S)[x \cup {x} \in S]]$ to define an infinite set composed of all real numbers, for all integers, or just for all real numbers between $0$ and $1$. An explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In set theory, real numbers are sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many good questions here about constructions of the real numbers. For example [Completion of rational numbers via Cauchy sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11923/completion-of-rational-numbers-via-cauchy-sequences).

Note that the Axiom of Infinity is *only* used to guarantee existence of the ordinal $\omega$. The rest of the ordinals and other sets follow from the other axioms.

Comment: That could be misleading. Without the Axiom of Infinity, you don't get *any* infinite ordinals. What you mean is that the Axiom of Infinity gives you $\omega$, while you need the Axiom of Infinity plus the other axioms to get you the rest of the ordinals.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/476076/462).