# Equivalence of two formulations of the axiom of infinity

Tags: set-theory, axioms, foundations

I'm introducing [Zermelo–Fraenkel axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) in a minimal way: only what is actually needed to introduce real numbers.

In this respect I noticed that I do not need the axiom of foundation nor the axiom of replacement. Instead I define functions as soon as possible, so it is natural to define an infinite set as a set $X$ such that there exists $f\colon X\to X$ injective, but not [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) (Dedekind-infinite) before having natural numbers.

So my statement of the axiom of infinity is: "there exists a (Dedekind-)infinite set". The usual axiom of infinity requires instead the existence of the first infinite ordinal $\omega$. If I have $\omega$ it is not difficult to prove that $\omega$ is Dedekind-infinite.

On the other hand it seems to me that without the replacement axiom it is possible that an infinite set exists even if $\omega$ does not exist. This makes sense to me: why should I suppose the existence of $\omega$ if I don't really need it?

However, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472045/a-weaker-axiom-of-infinity/472048#472048) states that the equivalence of the two formulations can be obtained only with [extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality), [pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_pairing), [unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union), [specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) and [powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_power_set#Consequences). How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not true.  Consider the set $X=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\},\dots\}$.  Let $M$ be the closure of $X\cup\{X\}$ under the operations of taking subsets, forming pairs, forming power sets, and taking unions.  Then $M$ will be a transitive model of the Extensionality, Pairing, Union, Specification, and Powerset axioms (and also Regularity and Choice), as well as your version of Infinity since there is a non-surjective injection $f:X\to X$ given by $f(x)=\{x\}$.  However, I claim that $\omega\not\in M$.  To prove this, just note that for every $x\in M$, the transitive closure of $x$ contains only finitely many elements of $\omega$ (since this is true of $X\cup\{X\}$ and is preserved by all the operations we close it under to form $M$).

Comment: Many thanks, very clear! Can you give an hint or a reference to the construction of $\omega$ when you instead assume also the replacement axiom?

Comment: Given a Dedekind-infinite set, you can get a model of the natural numbers (take an element not in the image of $f$ to be "$0$" and then take the closure of that element under $f$).  Develop the usual theory of recursion on these natural numbers and then recursively define the function $g$ on $\mathbb{N}$ given by $g(0)=\emptyset$, $g(n+1)=g(n)\cup\{n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an alternative approach:
Let $X=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\},\ldots\}$.
Define recursively
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}\emptyset&\text{if }x\in X\setminus\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\\\{\,f(y)\mid y\in x\,\}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
and let $M$ be the class of sets  $x$ such that $f(x)$ is hereditarily finite.
Then $M$ is closed under Pairing, taking subsets (hence under Specification), Union, and Powerset. Clearly $X\in M$ and $\omega\notin M$ and we have the injective non-surjective map $s\colon X\to X$, $x\mapsto \{x\}$.

Incidentally, (using Kuratowksy pairs) its graph $\{\,\langle x,s(x)\rangle \mid x\in X\,\}$ is also $\in M$ because for almost all $x\in X$, we have
$$ f(\langle x,s(x)\rangle)=f(\{\{x\},\{x,s(x)\}\})=\{f(\{x\}),f(\{x,s(x)\})\}
=\{\emptyset,\{f(x),f(s(x))\}\}
=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset,\emptyset\}\}=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$$